# Check empty after a HTML element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using `.after()` like below for Form Validation

```
$("#contactNum").after(
    '<span class="invalid-feedback">Please fill up this Field.</span>'
);
```

I would like to check if this `span` is present or absent to avoid add this `span` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the next element after your `contactNum` doesn't have particular class i.e `invalid-feedback` using this add your span tag.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//using class
if (!$("#contactNum").next().hasClass("invalid-feedback")) {
  $("#contactNum").after(
    '<span class="invalid-feedback">Please fill up this Field.</span>'
  );
}
/*
//using text
if ($("#contactNum").next().text().trim() != "Please fill up this Field.".trim()) {
  $("#contactNum").after(
    '<span class="invalid-feedback">Please fill up this Field.</span>'
  );
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="contactNum">
<span class="invalid-feedback">Please fill up this Field.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just check the next span length using `next` and `length` and if already have span you can just fill up text otherwise you can `insertAfter` check below code.

```js
if( !$('#contactNum').next('span.invalid-feedback').length ){
    $('<span class="invalid-feedback">Please fill up this Field.</span>').insertAfter($('#contactNum'));
}else{
    $('#contactNum').next('span.invalid-feedback').text('Please fill up this Field.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="contactNum">
```